# Setting usable area of the screen

Tags: x11, window-manager, dock

I am creating a dock for my own usage.

The problem is, when I maximize a window, window takes dock's space too.

Is there a way to restrict the area used by other windows?

I guess it is related to my window manager, but I am stuck with how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Which dock are you using? Dock should have a setting to change the layer in which it is in. If not window manager like fluxbox provides such function for each window instances. More info needed.

Comment: Actually, I am developing a dock for my own taste. I didn't try it, but looks like my problem could be solved by setting X11 window type _NET_WM_TYPE_DOCK.